# How to set asc and desc with variable in sequel postgresql adapter in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I would like to do orderby query with dynamic variable posted from client.
Client shows data tables and I am going to do orderby when user click header of each column.
So I post orderby variable to server api.
but I am not sure how to set asc and desc with variable.
The reason of this requirement is, I have to set orderby name also variable.

I post these two params `orderby, orderdir`
for example, `orderby='name', orderdir='asc'`

In this case how to modify this static sequel?

```
Artist.order(Sequel.desc(:name))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, as Pablo said, allowing the user/attacker control over which column to order is a bad and possibly dangerous idea.  To be safe, you should use a whitelist.  The code Pablo gave doesn't work with Sequel, but this should:

```
ord = case params['orderby']
when 'age'
  :age
else
  :name
end

ord = Sequel.desc(ord) if params['orderdir'] == 'desc'
Artist.order(ord)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use what you receive in the params directly or you can have serious risks.
Just analyze params in the controller.

```
order = case params[:orderby]
  when "name" then "name"
  when "age" then "age"
  else "name"
end

# Wrong version as Jeremy said.
# order = order + " desc" if params[:orderdir] == 'desc'
order = Sequel.desc(order) if params[:orderdir] == 'desc'

Artist.order(order)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways which I know of. You can use any one of them based on your requirement:

1) If you are ordering the records on the basis of the field of artist object itself then use this:

```
Artist.order("#{orderby + ' ' + orderdir}")
```

2) If you are ordering records on the basis of the field of associated records then use this:
  Let's take an example here 
  Artist belongs to some category and we want to order artists on by name of category then

```
Artist.send("order_with_#{orderby + '_' + orderdir}")
```

Lets suppose if you wanted to order Artist on the basis of

```
orderby='category_name', orderdir='asc'
```

then This will call a class method *'order_with_category_name_asc'*

So either you can create a scope

```
scope :order_with_category_name_asc, -> { includes(:category).order("categories.name") }
```

or can create a class method which also do the same

```
def self.order_with_category_name_asc
  self.includes(:category).order("categories.name")
end
```

Please let me know if you need any other help.